# YouTrack How to display sprint info in issue table

Tags: youtrack, sprint

I need to find a way to display info to which sprint issue is assigned in issues table.
Two possible ways I see:

1. Through List Settings
2. With automatic assign of tags to issue in Sprint №

Probably there are other solutions.
Solutions for YouTrack Lite is preferable.

[List Settings in Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuiNJ.png)
[Tag in issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHiNX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Both options are valid. The most common one would be using the list settings though. The main idea here is to link a sprint to a specific field value. For example, you create a field called Sprint (or whatever you want), and this field's values correspond with your sprints. For that, boards have a special setting called [Link Sprints to Values for Custom Field﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Sprint-Options.html#link-sprints-new).

After that, all you need to do is to add this sprint field to the issue list.